# Asp.net MVC-5 Identity suddenly not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm developing web in Asp.Net Mvc5. But today suddenly I can't login /Using identity/.

Here's my login action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel input, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string personalNo = AppStaticConfig.ServiceController.PupilLogin(input.Code, input.Password, ModelState);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(personalNo))
            {
                PupilProfile pp = AppStaticConfig.ServiceController.PupilDetail(personalNo, AppStaticConfig.SchoolID, ModelState);

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, pp.pupil.LastName.Substring(0, 1) + "." + pp.pupil.FirstName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, personalNo),
                    new Claim("pupilCode", input.Code)
                },
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role); 

                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "guest"));

                    Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties{ IsPersistent = true }, identity);

                TempData["pp"] = pp;
                return RedirectToAction("PupilProfile", "Pupil");
            }
        }

        return View(input);
    }
```

And here's Pupil controller's PupilProfile action which redirected after successful login:

```
[Authorize]
public class PupilController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PupilProfile()
    {
        PupilProfile pp = TempData["pp"] != null ? TempData["pp"] as PupilProfile : AppStaticConfig.ServiceController.PupilDetail(User.Identity.GetUserId(), AppStaticConfig.SchoolID, ModelState);
        return View(pp);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is User.Identity not setting in `Authentication.SignIn`.

Any1 has idea what's wrong?

Comment: Everytime when I try to login it's redirecting back to login page immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved.** Was some environment problem I think.

What I was tried to fix:

1. Clear all cache cookie in browser. /But was no success/
2. Reset VS2013 settings from 'Import export menu'
3. Restart OS /my os:Win8.1/
4. Relaunched and problem was solved.

Hope it help some1.

Comment: I was having the same thing. Was using firefox and when you spoke about clearing browser cache, I decided to use Chrome, and voila, problem didnt exist.

Comment: I tried running in Edge and it worked, then I cleared Chrome's cache, cookies, passwords, et al and it's working in Chrome again. Such a weird problem! I mean, how can Chrome cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

i just switched to different browser and that was all.